# C# or C++ How to make program to run when user password asked?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, startup

I've such a problem, I need my program to run when user password asked(when computer is switched on). I know there is a class RegistryKey in both C++ and C# but they make program to start when the user logged in. Is there any I can do that?

Comment: Write a **Windows service**. I'll let you research it by yourself, there's plenty of documentation around.

Comment: If you're not logged on, in which "context" will you run the program?
Some or the other user has to log in to run a user program.

Comment: @Vandesh I don't want the program to run for any user, I want it just to work in background...

Comment: @Vandesh That's the whole point of services (aka. daemons in Unix parlance): they don't need an interactive session, so they can be run before any user logs in.

Comment: "I need my program to run" got me thinking its a user created executable or something. True that for services!

Comment: There's nothing you can do in a service that lets you interact with the secure desktop, the one that shows the password prompt.  Obviously that would be a major security leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone I've used windows service.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the function [*CreateService* in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SC_HANDLE WINAPI CreateService(
  _In_       SC_HANDLE hSCManager,
  _In_       LPCTSTR lpServiceName,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpDisplayName,
  _In_       DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_       DWORD dwServiceType,
  _In_       DWORD dwStartType,
  _In_       DWORD dwErrorControl,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpBinaryPathName,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpLoadOrderGroup,
  _Out_opt_  LPDWORD lpdwTagId,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpDependencies,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpServiceStartName,
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpPassword
);
```

For **dwStartType** use **SERVICE_AUTO_START**

For **lpServiceStartName** you can either use **NULL** to make it use the LocalSystem account, or any of the following: **NT AUTHORITY\LocalService** or **NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService**. To find out more about what the different accounts can offer, read up on [Service User Accounts in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For the **lpPassword** you can use **NULL** if you used any of the values above.

For the **lpBinaryPathName** you must put the file path to your service.

If you are unsure about the other you should have a look at the **sample code** ["*A basic Windows service in C++ (CppWindowsService)*" in the MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948). The sample code would probably be a good starting point.